# Stop a Decorator on React Final Form

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

How do you stop a decorator after it has been passed to the Form from react-final-form? I want to stop the field from being auto calculated if the field is touched and changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not currently possible. You might have to make your own version of `final-form-calculate`. Or try to engineer it into `final-form-calculate` and submit a PR.

Comment: What about the disconnect method that is returned?

Comment: I don’t think that’s available to you when using react-final-form.